# box2d + cocos2d: Why is there a delay when manipulating objects in box 2d using mouseJoint

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

When I drag an object in my game, the object is never directly under the finger. There us this lag / delay that I cannot get rid of. It follows my finger instead of being directly underneath it. You can try in the Testbed as well. Trying moving an object really fast and the object is never underneath the mouse/finger

Is this a weakness in box2d? Or am I missing something obvious ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `mouseJoint` is similar to `distantJoint` (spring). There is a `maxForce` parameter you can specify to minimize the delay - make the spring more hard.

**EDIT:**

Also you can move your object directly specifying it's position to your finger position. But if this object will collide with something it will provide non-physical behavior because the velocity of the body will be zero.

So to move it correctly (if there will be collisions) you should specify it's velocity or acceleration (as mouse joint does). But to evaluate your finger velocity you will need some time and delay will remain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like I am already setting maxForce to a really high number :) I guess I will have to live with this delay

md1.maxForce = 9999999.0f * _Body->GetMass();
  
_mouseJoint = (b2MouseJoint *)_world->CreateJoint(&md1);

Answer (score 0):

Most of it has to do with latency in the hardware. If your timings are completely perfect, their will be 16ms of lag caused by the iPhone's GPU, ~20ms of lag from the touchscreen, and then how ever long the processing takes for your scene. So those add up to anywhere between 36-70ms of lag. Also, there is a small amount of damping applied in box2d on the mouse joint, for stability of the physics simulation.